# foreach is not function,how to solve this? js

Tags: javascript, html

i building caraousel container but there is a problem in this part.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLYiq.jpg)

```
  span class="cursor1" id="cursor1">&#10094;</span>
  <span class="cursor2" id="cursor2">&#10095;</span>
  <div class="kategori-container">
  <div class="border-box" id="border-box" >
  <div class="kategori-item">
  <div class="thumbler-bg"></div>
  <div class="produk-thumbler">
  <img class="thumbler-img" src="feature/images__15_-removebg-preview.png" alt="" srcset="">
  <div class="kategori-text">
  <span>produk kucing</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
const featureContainers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.border-box')];
// console.log(featureContainers)
const cursorRight = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cursor1')];
const cursorLeft = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cursor2')];

featureContainers[0].forEach((objek, ruang) => {
let featureDimensions = objek.getBoundingClientRect();
let featureWidth = featureDimensions.width;
// console.log(ruang);
cursorRight[ruang].addEventListener('click', () => {
  objek.scrollLeft += featureWidth;
})
cursorLeft[ruang].addEventListener('click', () => {
  objek.scrollLeft -= featureWidth;
})

});
```

i'm stuck here,can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you expect `featureContainers[0].forEach` to be a function?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: Please don't fundamentally change an existing question to address a new problem.  This invalidates existing responses and makes it confusing and useless to future readers.  If you have a new error, you are encouraged to ask a new question.  In that new question, please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also, don't change the title to ask for something different that has nothing to do with the error/script in the body of the question (and that isn't even a problem/error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` runs on array.. you are invoking it on first element using `[0]`

so instead of

`featureContainers[0].forEach`

do

`featureContainers.forEach`

Comment: Why is this not "just a typo" and therefor a close vote?

Comment: I've changed according to your instructions but instead changed the appearance to:script.js:115 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:115:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at script.js:111:19
(anonymous) @ script.js:115
(anonymous) @ script.js:111

Comment: @zazazaa Then there are more "containers" than "cursors"